VSCode is not using Git Credential Manager from host within Remote SSH environment
I just wanted to know if it is possible to forward Git Credential Manager from my Windows host to an Ubuntu VM through Remote SSH extension like we can do with Dev Containers.
I tried to clone (with HTTPS) a project from Azure DevOps and the Credential Manager helper only worked in my host and in a dev container. It seems that the git credential.helper field is not populated in SSH hosts like it is in dev containers.
